# How do I transfer spl token using web3 and wallet adapter through only pubKey of sender

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, web3.js

I want to transfer the spl-token using solana web3 and a wallet adapter (phantom) having only the public key of the sender

Comment: You're definitely not able to send SPL tokens from a sender using only their PublicKey. You need the sender's signature, and that can only come from their private key (Keypair). 

Are you asking how to send to the sender? or from the sender?

Comment: No, I need to send through phantom wallet while using solana web3. Is there no way to send with web3 and phantom wallet ?

Answer (score 1):

The sender always need to sign for the transaction, since it will be debited and not credited.
You should be able to sign / approve it directly from your wallet, but it needs to be connected